# is there any way to run aks in azure dev/test labs?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-devtest-labs

I am looking a way to run aks or k8s cluster in dev/test labs but I couldn't find an official way. I guess Azure has allow using production services in Dev/Test Lab however they haven't published yet a document to achieve this. I need rich memory VMs such as 128/256 gb though AKS doesn't support that vm on cluster. And AutoShutdown option will be cost saving for these VMs. So I have to build this in dev/test lab. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.danielstechblog.io/adding-value-devtest-labs-users-additional-azure-services/

Comment: the problem is I already tried this blog but there are many gaps between steps and I cannot show any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AKS is a managed service and you can't run it on you own VMs or the ones from Dev/Test Labs.  Why are you saying that you can't use 128/256GB RAM VMs?  When selecting your VMs size in the portal, make sure to select the Memory Optimized family.

If I understand correctly, your goal is to save money running these high cost VMs.  One possible way you can achieve this is create your cluster with a single instance of a smaller VM and create a a second node pool with the larger VMs.  You can then create and destroy that second pool on demand.

Comment: @CSSharpRocks, do you have any evidence from Microsoft Documentation that we cannot create an AKS Cluster in Dev Test Lab?